# Loop through Array in php find value stop loop and echo header

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
foreach($resorts as $askiarea)
{

    $askiarea = (array) $askiarea;

    $askiarea['ReportType'] = $askiarea['resortStatus'];

    $flag=1;


    if (($askiarea['ReportType'] ==6) || ($askiarea['ReportType'] =="6"))
    {

        if($flag ==1)

    echo '<tr><th colspan="6" text-align="left"><div class="region-headline">Opening Soon For Snow Sports</div></th></tr>';}

    $flag = 0;



 }
```

The header only need to be echoed once after the value is found for ReportType every time I try this I get multiply headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use break statement.

```
foreach($resorts as $askiarea) {
    $askiarea = (array) $askiarea;
    $askiarea['ReportType'] = $askiarea['resortStatus'];
    if (($askiarea['ReportType'] ==6) || ($askiarea['ReportType'] == "6")) {
        echo '<tr><th colspan="6" text-align="left"><div class="region-headline">Opening Soon For Snow Sports</div></th></tr>';}
        break;
    }
}
```

More about break [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)

Answer (score 0):

Please add curly braces:

```
if($flag ==1) {

    echo '<tr><th colspan="6" text-align="left"><div class="region-headline">Opening Soon For Snow Sports</div></th></tr>';}

    $flag = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `$flag = 1` in each iteration before checking the ReportType, so of course the header will be printed in each iteration. The `$flag = 0` is not doing anything there.

Set `$flag = 1` before the foreach loop and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

A little unsure how your array looks to begin with, but here is a very simplified example:

```
<?php
$resorts = [0=>['ReportType'=>6],1=>['ReportType'=>6],2=>['ReportType'=>"6"]];

for ($c = 0; $c < count($resorts); $c++) {
    if ($resorts[$c]['ReportType'] == 6) {
        echo '<tr><th colspan="6" text-align="left"><div class="region-headline">Opening Soon For Snow Sports</div></th></tr>';
        break;
    }
} 
?>
```

It counts the original array (I assume it's a multidimensional array?) and iterates the value based on that, and breaks if it's found. There is no differentiation in PHP between an int and a string, so there is no need to check for both `== 6` and `== "6"`.